# Multiple onclick event in front end to hit into web API using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, webapi

I have three tap like Jan, Feb and March, onclick the events in multiple time its the results (5 times), 6th time did not get the results from Web API.

At the time passing the parameter via Postman did not the get the result through

> {
> "message": "An error has occurred." }

front end service.js

```
return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: AppConfig.serviceUrl + targetPath,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataToPost
})
```

In server just save the **web.config** file from web API its working fine

Where is the issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you better

Comment: Controller.js try {

            Service.methodNameFromService(params).then(function (response) {response} service.js :this.methodNameFromService= function (params) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var targetPath = 'api url';
        DataSvc.POSTData(deferred, targetPath, params, DataSvc);
        return deferred.promise;
    }